# How to change the bytes in a file?

Tags: python, unicode, binary, ascii, encode

I'm making a encryption program and I need to open file in binary mode to access non-ascii and non-printable characters, I need to check if character from a file is letter, number, symbol or unprintable character. That means I have to check 1 by 1 if bytes (when they are decoded to ascii) match any of these characters:

```
{^9,dzEV=Q4ciT+/s};fnq3BFh% #2!k7>YSU<GyD\I]|OC_e.W0M~ua-jR5lv1wA`@8t*xr'K"[P)&b:g$p(mX6Ho?JNZL
```

I think I could encode these characters above to binary and then compare them with bytes. I don't know how to do this.

> P.S. Sorry for bad English and binary misunderstanding. (I hope you
>   know what I mean by bytes, I mean characters in binary mode like
>   this):

```
\x01\x00\x9a\x9c\x18\x00
```

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?  The reason I ask is because bytes objects are different to native strings in Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two major string types in Python: bytestrings (a sequence of bytes) that represent binary data and Unicode strings (a sequence of Unicode codepoints) that represent human-readable text. It is simple to convert one into another (☯):

```
unicode_text = bytestring.decode(character_encoding)
bytestring = unicode_text.encode(character_encoding)
```

If you open a file in binary mode e.g., `'rb'` then `file.read()` returns a bytestring (`bytes` type):

```
>>> b'A' == b'\x41' == chr(0b1000001).encode()
True
```

---

There are several methods that can be used to classify bytes:

- string methods such as `bytes.isdigit()`:

  ```
  >>> b'1'.isdigit()
  True
  ```
- string constants such as `string.printable`

  ```
  >>> import string
  >>> b'!' in string.printable.encode()
  True
  ```
- regular expressions such as `\d`

  ```
  >>> import re
  >>> bool(re.match(br'\d+$', b'123'))
  True
  ```
- classification functions in `curses.ascii` module e.g., `curses.ascii.isprint()`

  ```
  >>> from curses import ascii
  >>> bytearray(filter(ascii.isprint, b'123'))
  bytearray(b'123')
  ```

`bytearray` is a mutable sequence of bytes — unlike a bytestring you can change it inplace e.g., to lowercase every 3rd byte that is uppercase:

```
>>> import string
>>> a = bytearray(b'ABCDEF_')
>>> uppercase = string.ascii_uppercase.encode()
>>> a[::3] = [b | 0b0100000 if b in uppercase else b 
...           for b in a[::3]]
>>> a
bytearray(b'aBCdEF_')
```

Notice: `b'ad'` are lowercase but `b'_'` remained the same.

---

To modify a binary file inplace, you could use `mmap` module e.g., to lowercase 4th column in every other line in `'file'`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import mmap
import string

uppercase = string.ascii_uppercase.encode()
ncolumn = 3 # select 4th column
with open('file', 'r+b') as file, \
     mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE) as mm:
    while True:
        mm.readline()   # ignore every other line
        pos = mm.tell() # remember current position
        if not mm.readline(): # EOF
            break
        if mm[pos + ncolumn] in uppercase:
            mm[pos + ncolumn] |= 0b0100000 # lowercase
```

Note: Python 2 and 3 APIs differ in this case. The code uses Python 3.

#### Input

```
ABCDE1
FGHIJ
ABCDE
FGHI
```

#### Output

```
ABCDE1
FGHiJ
ABCDE
FGHi
```

Notice: 4th column became lowercase on 2nd and 4h lines.

---

Typically if you want to change a file: you read from the file, write modifications to a temporary file, and on success you move the temporary file inplace of the original file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import string
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

caesar_shift = 3
filename = 'file'

def caesar_bytes(plaintext, shift, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase.encode()):
    shifted_alphabet = alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift]
    return plaintext.translate(plaintext.maketrans(alphabet, shifted_alphabet))

dest_dir = os.path.dirname(filename)
chunksize = 1 << 15
with open(filename, 'rb') as file, \
     NamedTemporaryFile('wb', dir=dest_dir, delete=False) as tmp_file:
    while True: # encrypt
        chunk = file.read(chunksize)
        if not chunk: # EOF
            break
        tmp_file.write(caesar_bytes(chunk, caesar_shift))
os.replace(tmp_file.name, filename)
```

#### Input

```
abc
def
ABC
DEF
```

#### Output

```
def
ghi
ABC
DEF
```

To convert the output back, set `caesar_shift = -3`.

Answer (score 0):

To open a file in binary mode you use the `open("filena.me", "rb")` command. I've never used the command personally, but that should get you the information you need.