# Python Pickled Passwords

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

This is my python password system using pickle. It's bad, I know, but it's my first time with pickle.

```
import pickle
import os

userlist = {'user1':'userpass1', 'user2':'userpass2'}

users = open ("users.pkl", 'wb')

pickle.dump (userlist, users)

username = input ("Enter your username: ")
password = input ("Enter your password: ")

if (username in userlist) and (password == userlist[username]):
    print ("Access Granted")
else:
   newaccount = input ("User not found. Shall I create a new account? ")
    if newaccount == "yes":
       username = input ("Please enter your username: ")
       password = input ("Please enter yout password: ")
       userlist.update({username:password})
       pickle.dump (userlist, users)
       users.close()
```

My problem is that, whenever I go to add a new account, using this part:

```
 newaccount = input ("User not found. Shall I create a new account? ")
    if newaccount == "yes":
        username = input ("Please enter your username: ")
        password = input ("Please enter yout password: ")
        userlist.update({username:password})
        pickle.dump (userlist, users)
        users.close()
```

It seems to add it (and it looks like it's there in the pickle file using notepad) but, I restart the python file, and it does not see it.

I believe it is something to do with this part:

```
userlist = {'user1':'userpass1', 'user2':'userpass2'}

users = open ("users.pkl", 'wb')

pickle.dump (userlist, users)
```

Any help is appreciated! :D

Comment: passwords belong to a very special category. Even simple things should be done differently with passwords e.g., don't store them in plain text, don't hardcode passwords in the source code.

Comment: I know, but this is for school - not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You overwrite each time you run the program with `w`:

```
users = open ("users.pkl", 'wb')
```

If you wanted to get the previously pickled items you would  need to see if the file already exists and  `pickle.load` to get the previously pickled items and then `dump` at the end of your code.

Something like the following:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

try:
    # see if we have run  this before
    with  open ("users.pkl", 'rb') as users:
       users_dict = pickle.load(users)
except IOError:
    # if not set to defualt
    users_dict = {'user1':'userpass1', 'user2':'userpass2'}


username = input ("Enter your username: ")
password = input ("Enter your password: ")

if users_dict.get(username) == password: # unless a password can be None we can use get
    print ("Access Granted")
else:
    newaccount = input("User not found. Shall I create a new account? ")
    if newaccount == "yes":
       username = input("Please enter your username: ")
       password = input ("Please enter yout password: ")
       users_dict[username] = password # just use key = value

with NamedTemporaryFile("wb",dir=os.path.dirname("users.pkl"),delete=False) as f: # in case we get exception use temp file
    pickle.dump (users_dict, f)
os.replace(f.name,"users.pkl") # update original
```

Comment: you can't write to a file that is opened using `rb` mode.

Comment: you should probably use `with`-statement for the `users` file too (I don't know whether you can open an already opened file on Windows). Write to a temporary file and use `os.replace()` at the end -- otherwise the password database will be lost if an error occurs during `pickle.dump`. It won't help if multiple instances of this program may run simultaneously or if [the power is lost suddenly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2333872/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, yes, I thought I had closed the  original file but using with is probably better anyway.

Comment: I meant [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28522826/4279) (note: it is important to set `dir`).