# How to write to dump file in HEX after reading in python 2.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, hex

As per the title I need help with writing to a specific byte in a dump file. So far I'm able to read 512 byte with the following code :

```
sectorcount = 0;
bytecount= 0;
with open('a2.dump', 'rb') as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(16), b''):
        #16 bytes per chunk aka 32 characters
        item = chunk.encode('hex')
        #to filter display output so it shows 2 character per array element
        filtered_item= [item[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(item), 2)]
        #to display in "hex" form
        #filtered_item[0] = "E5"


        print ' '.join(filtered_item)
        sectorcount = sectorcount +1
        #to display 1 sector use the value 32. adjust accordingly"
        if sectorcount ==32:
            break
```

The result shown were

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 77 8a 1c 22 00 00 00 21
03 00 83 37 ee fb 00 08 00 00 00 b8 3d 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa
```

As you can see I would need help in editing one of those values in the results (e.g. changing the value of "77" to maybe "E1")

I tried opening the file as `with open('a2.dump', 'wb') as f:` but my dump file got nulled. I believe i need to use the write operation to the file but unsure how to do it in Hex aka binary form in Python.

Appreciate any help in advance ! Thanks !

EDIT:
As per James Sebastian request the I created a .dump file and edited them in HexEdit with my results shown above.

I then execute the code `print repr(open('input.dump', 'rb').read())`
Results as shown are:

```
'\x00w\x8a\x1c"\x00'
```

The corresponding expected output (the result after the replacements):

```
'\x00\xe1\x8a\x1c"\x00'
```

Comment: I compared this results and it is similar in HexEdit. 
In my understanding 1 character in the result is 1 byte. 
so '00' in my results is 2 bytes

Comment: I have understood the need to use 'ab+' because i need to append which is why 'wb' got the file replaced and overwritten.
Question now is how to write to each specific byte ?

Comment: I need to edit the file contents. Refer to my results above assuming that you need to replace one of the pairs (e.g. replace "77" with "E1"). How do i write "E1" to replace "77" ?

Comment: how does it not ? All i have to do is find the hexadecimal of "77" within the file and replace it with "E1". How do i actually replace that hexadecumal value with another value within the file ? Plain enough ?

Comment: Why do you need to modify the original file? Why can't you read from the old file and write to a new file? Is the file huge?

Comment: Yes it is. As a matter of fact it is 2GB +

Comment: Ok. In that case it makes a lot of sense to modify the file in-place. :)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian memory error

Comment: sorry used wrong input file. see edits

Comment: As well as my code below, you may also like to see an example I wrote a few months ago of in-place modification of a text file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32098399/4014959

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short demo of doing hex search & replace in a binary file. I took a 32 byte excerpt of your data; here's its hex dump (produced using hd on Linux).

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  77 8a 1c 22 00 00 00 21  |........w.."...!|
00000010  03 00 83 37 ee fb 00 08  00 00 00 b8 3d 00 00 00  |...7........=...|
00000020
```

Here's the code:

```python
fname = 'qdata'
with open(fname, 'r+b') as f:
    #save position of the start of the data block
    fprev = f.tell()
    stringdata = f.read(32)
    print stringdata.encode('hex')

    #replace the first occurence of \x77\x8a with \xe1\x8a
    newdata = stringdata.replace('\x77\x8a', '\xe1\x8a')
    print newdata.encode('hex')

    #rewind file to the start of the data block
    f.seek(fprev)
    f.write(newdata)
```

Note that file mode is `'r+b'`. This lets us read the file and also modify it. If you open it with a `w` mode the file is truncated, i.e., its previous contents get wiped out, and the file size is reset to zero. If you open it in an `a` mode the file pointer is positioned at the end of the file to allow data to be appended.

Here's the output that the above code prints:

```
0000000000000000778a1c220000002103008337eefb0008000000b83d000000
0000000000000000e18a1c220000002103008337eefb0008000000b83d000000
```

We don't *need* to do those `.encode('hex')` and`print` steps, they're purely informational, so we can see what the program's doing.

Here's the hexdump of the modified file:

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  e1 8a 1c 22 00 00 00 21  |..........."...!|
00000010  03 00 83 37 ee fb 00 08  00 00 00 b8 3d 00 00 00  |...7........=...|
00000020
```

In the above code I read the entire file contents into RAM; that's certainly not necessary, you can scan it block by block, or however you see fit. But you **must** do a file `.seek()` call in between file `.read()` and `.write()` operations.

Also, be *very* careful that you get the positioning correct. And don't accidentally write the wrong data length. It won't change the file length, but it can still make a mess of your file if your replacement data isn't the length you think it is.

---

Here's a function that modifies file data at a given offset. Because its action is potentially dangerous the function prompts the user to make sure that the correct data is being overwritten. In the test code I use the same 32 byte file as before, overwriting the 3 bytes `'\x83\x37\xee'` at offset 0x12.

```
def binedit(fname, offset, newdata):
    with open(fname, 'r+b') as f:
        #Show current contents
        f.seek(offset)
        stringdata = f.read(len(newdata))
        print 'Current data:'
        print '%08X: %s\n' % (offset, stringdata.encode('hex'))

        prompt = 'Replace with %s ? (y/N) ' % newdata.encode('hex')
        s = raw_input(prompt)
        if s != 'y':
            print 'Aborting'
            return

        #Replace data at offset with newdata
        f.seek(offset)
        f.write(newdata)


fname = 'qdata'
offset = 0x12
newdata = 'dead42'.decode('hex')
binedit(fname, offset, newdata)
```

**output**

```
Current data:
00000012: 8337ee

Replace with dead42 ? (y/N) y
```

The "before" and "after" hex dumps:

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  77 8a 1c 22 00 00 00 21  |........w.."...!|
00000010  03 00 83 37 ee fb 00 08  00 00 00 b8 3d 00 00 00  |...7........=...|
00000020

00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  77 8a 1c 22 00 00 00 21  |........w.."...!|
00000010  03 00 de ad 42 fb 00 08  00 00 00 b8 3d 00 00 00  |....B.......=...|
00000020
```

Disclaimer: If you destroy valuable data using this code it's not my fault!

Comment: nice code. but is there a way where i can be specific about the positioning of my editing instead of searching for a pattern ? (e.g. i would like to edit at the position of \x01x003 which in this case is "83")

Comment: @misctpasdas: Your position notation looks a little odd to me, but I'll add some new code to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

To replace a byte in a binary file, you don't need a hex dump e.g., to replace `b'\x77'` with `b'\xE1'`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import mmap
from contextlib import closing

with open('a2.dump', 'r+b') as file, \
     closing(mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)) as s:
    i = -1
    while 1:
        i = s.find(b'\x77', i+1)
        if i < 0: # not found
            break
        s[i] = b'\xE1'[0] # replace
```

It performs the replacements inplace. It works for arbitrary large files.

For example, if the input file is created using:

```
open('a2.dump','wb').write(b'\x00w\x8a\x1c"\x00')
```

then the output (after the `77 -> E1` replacement) is:

```
print(repr(open('a2.dump','rb').read()))
# -> b'\x00\xe1\x8a\x1c"\x00'
```

Notice that `0x77` byte is replaced with `0xE1`.

See [Python - How can I change bytes in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28520922/4279).

Comment: i need to operate on a no-dependencies basis where the script may be applied in any linux system with portability. as such i cant use this code as is has dependencies on other APIs

Comment: @misctpasdas: have you tried to run it? It has no dependencies. `mmap` is in stdlib and it is available on Linux (among other platforms).

Comment: thanks. Is there any way i could edit the bytes based on location within the file instead of searching for a pattern ?

Comment: @misctpasdas: yes. Look at `s[i]` in the code. `i` is the offset in bytes (an integer).

Comment: how about import closing ? is it part of stdlib as well ?

Comment: btw this code didnt worked as my file was 2GB big and it came back with the error WindowsError: [Error 8] Not enough storage is available to process this command

Comment: @misctpasdas: (1) it is part of stdlib. Type `help('contextlib')` in Python console. (2) `mmap` works with large files even they do not fit in memory. (I've just tried 50GB file and it works ok). If it doesn't work for you then create a separate question: provide the *exact* code that you use (a minimal code that shows the issue), provide the full traceback of the error, run `python -mplatform` and add it to your new question. There are workarounds if your OS doesn't allow to mmap the whole file at once (you could pass offset + length)